# struct.packing won't work for me

Tags: python, data-structures, tcp

i will be straight forward:

this command:

```
chat_manager.send(self.player, protocol.KA().encode("h"))
```

raises this eception:

[image]

chat_manager.send (spacings went wrong. ignore):

```
def send(player, data):
try:
    player.send(data)
except ConnectionAbortedError:
    player.stop()
    if player.server == None:
        player.queue_thread.stop()
        print("server has been closed")
        print("closing program")
        exit()
        print("program closed")
```

player.send is a regular TcpIp client send.

protocol.KA().encode("h"):

```
def encode(self, data):
    return self._pack_string(self.msg_id, data)

def _pack_string(self, msg_id, s):
    s = bytes(s, 'utf-8')
    l = len(s)
    print(str(l) +" " + str(s))
    data = struct.pack("II%ds" %l, msg_id, l, s)
    return data
```

the question is:

what does the error mean? how do i fix it?

thank you

(KA = Keep Alive. if you need any more code tell me)

(print outcome: 1 b'h')

Comment: 'I' in format string, has standard size 4 bytes, right? So the range error might indicate that the int did not fit in 4 bytes (guessing ...)

Comment: @Dilettant see edit i added